# TYPO3: set a GET-parameter via Typoscript using the value of another GET-parameter

Tags: parameters, get, typo3

seem to be stuck at some quite simple point :-(:

In a TYPO3-project I want to / have to reuse one GET-parameter as if it was set to another param as well. As example: I have `my.tld/page/?param1=abc`, but in the end everything should work as if I had `my.tld/page/?param1=abc&param2=abc`.

The reason is that I have to use two plugins for search results on one target page (results for a quick search with one input field), where one is just the standard `tx_indexedsearch` (using the param `tx_indexedsearch[sword]`) and the other one (using let's say param `mysearchword`) is some specific solution with it's own data, not to be covered by `tx_indexedsearch`.

So my idea was to use the GET-value from my input field as one of these params (`tx_indexedsearch[sword]`) and set the other one (`mysearchword`) via Typoscript to the same value before rendering / executing the page.

Basically I can set a GET-value via `config.defaultGetVars` easily (or, depending on the extension via `tx_extension._DEFAULT_PI_VARS.param = abc`), but I just don't get it to work with some variable value (the one I get from the existing parameter).

If I try the following I never get the desired result (different alternative tries, see comments in code block)

```
# fetch the exisiting GET param tx_indexedsearch[sword]
lib.mysearchword = TEXT
lib.mysearchword.data = GP:tx_indexedsearch|sword

# try to use it to set GET param mysearchword
config.defaultGetVars {
  # next line leads to output "lib.mysearchword" (not the value)
  tx_otherextension.mysearchword = lib.mysearchword
  # next line leads to empty output ""
  # tx_otherextension.mysearchword < lib.mysearchword
  # next line leads to output "GP:tx_indexedsearch|sword" (not the value)
  # tx_otherextension.mysearchword = GP:tx_indexedsearch|sword
}
```

I pretty much assume I'm just really blind (or stupid, or both) - how can I solve that task? I should work inside Typoscript, I don't want to use JS to set some hidden input field for the second parameter upon submit of my search form. If possible (and because I just need that for one target page running the two plugins / showing results) I neither want to try simulating that via `realurl`.

Hopefully my description is not too weird - otherwise please ask for clarification.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cite: "_and the other one (using let's say param mysearchword) is some specific solution with it's own data_" does that mean you have your own plugin for this?

Comment: If it is used for 2 search 'extension'. I assume both values will be the same ? If so,  why use 2 parameters to set the value twice?  Can't you just use the same value for both plugins, bot reading the same value from the same parameter... ?

Comment: @biesior: yes, it's an extra plugin ("closed source" for me) coping with some own data model / logic (lets say a database of books). So I neither can influence the parameter the search part of that plugin needs / uses nor manage indexing of that "special" data by the standard tx_indexedsearch.

Comment: @rob-ot: sure, in general you're right it's kind of "stupid", because indeed both values shall be (must be) the same. If I had more influence on it or if it was my own plugin I sure would just handled it the way that the parameter is called the same for both - but I can't really do that. Of course I could try to fiddle around in the code of tx_indexedsearch or the tx_myotherplugin on my test system, but that would be pretty unhandy in the end, leading to problems with future updates, moves to another system and so on.

Comment: And can you modify the search box on the page? or is it also from "untouchable" ext?

Comment: If you can't touch nor the search ext form, nor the behaviour of the 'books' search application, the only best solution i see is to use js.  Or dom inject a hidden ghost field and fill it with the original value, or handle the form submit with js.

Comment: @biesior: the search box / input field is "mine", so I could modify it, but unless there's some unknown trick to let it have two "names" at a time, I did not get an idea how that would help me (despite some JS-thing copying the value).

Comment: @rob-ot thx - got some "worst case workaround" of that type already in mind, but I really would like to have something not relying on (possibly blocked) JS for that as I mentioned. Never thought that would really be so kind of tricky :-( - as I can easily set the GET parameter by Typoscript to any "hardcoded string" in my Typoscript I hoped I was just too stupid to get how to assign a variable value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think that easiest approach is modifying the search-box itself and setting the value of the hidden field before sending the form, this way you won't need to do any redirect or something to include additional param, pseudo-code:

```
<script>
    function sendSearchForm() {
        $('#mySearchWord').val($('#indexedSearchWord').val());
        $('#searchBox').submit();
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form action="/your/search/page.html" method="get" id="searchBox" onsubmit="sendSearchForm(); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="tx_indexedsearch[sword]" id="indexedSearchWord"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mysearchword" id="mySearchWord"/>
    <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank your for the snipplet - got that in mind as "fallback" if there's really no other (straight) way to do it, but still hoping for some solution avoiding JS. Some other nasty thing that just came up to my mind could be some iframe-thing wherefor I could probably easily build the src-attribute in my typoscript, but no - that's the worst way probably.

Comment: @biesior solution is imo the best. You can set the path of your search box to your own template, thus you can edit it without loosing your changes when you update the extension.

Comment: Yes, too bad that it really seems impossible to solve that via Typoscript, though - don't quite understand, why one can set GET-parameters in there, but not using some variable. Anyhow, had to get my thing running and so i chose the JS-thing I had in mind as fallback and @biesior showed in his answer for now. So I'll tag that as "solution, as long as no other 100% fitting solution comes up. Thank you all for help and ideas.

Comment: @Falcon2014 of course you can do it by bootstrapping your small FE plugin which will create redirect to the page with new argument in the URL, anyway just JS is faster.

Comment: Optionaly you can use both techniques to make sure that user didn't change it manually

Comment: @biesior thank you for the addition. Of course - stupid me - that could be another way, "simply" forwarding / redirecting somwhere, using my own url string built as needed. Just got stuck in my mind on the Typoscrip-thing ;-). Anyhow - for now it'll remain JS, the "more important" search plugin works with the original parameter without JS anyway and it's enough time spent on that small aspect.